# Rails Find Association Exclusively

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
class List < AR::Base
  has_many :items
end

class Item < AR::Base
  belongs_to :list
  att_accessible :tag
end
```

I'd like a method that returns only the List's with **all** the tags passed in to the method.

i.e. `filtered_lists = List.filter_by_item_tags(['tag1', 'tag2'])`

My current implementation returns a list with `tag1` or `tag2` I'd like it to return **only** the lists with **both** `tag1` and `tag2`

What I have so far:

```
class List < AR::Base
  def self.filter_by_item_tags(tags)
    items = Item.includes(:lists)
    items.find_all_by_tag(tags).map(&:lists).flatten
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [`joins` with condition](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables) may be helpful.
You can try something like this (I've not tested it)

```
def self.filter_by_item_tags(tags)
  # Get items with the given tag, and check that all tags have been found
  List.joins(:items).where("items.tag in (?) and count(distinct items.tag) = ?", tags, tags.length)
end
```

or

```
List.joins(:items).select('count(distinct items.tag) as tags_count').where(:items => { :tag => tags }).group('tags_count').having('tags_count = ?', tags.length)
```